# mainwindow shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

In my mainWindow.xib, I have this setup.

1) UINavigationController containing several viewControllers.

2) UIViewController containing a scrollview holding several buttons.

I've defined them in Appdelegate.h to get the control and attached them to window

```
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];      // navigationController
[window addSubview:container.view];                 //scrollview
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now I'm using the same standard code for InterfaceOrientation (In the AppDelegate and in all subsequent viewControllers in it.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) ? YES : NO;

}
```

The NavigationController and its subsequent viewControllers rotates as expected but the scrollview doesn't. Its position is fixed.

How can I rotate the container.view i.e scrollbar with buttons along with the navigationController whether using any If statement or defining a separate class for the scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want orientation change event in mainwindow you can use below method in app delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newStatusBarOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

check also [setAutoresizingMask:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) method and the associated resizing masks.

Comment: and how can I use it if the device changes the orientation like in my above example.